# How to integrate WITH Recursive in a Querydsl query

Tags: recursive-query, querydsl

I'm new to Querydsl and I'm struggling to figure out how to implement the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE results AS  
(  
   SELECT  id,  
           parent_id   
   FROM    project
   WHERE   id = '8a3d6714-27fa-4d1f-962f-9047d616ab42'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  t.id, 
           t.parent_id
   FROM    project t
   INNER JOIN results r ON r.parent_id = t.id
)
SELECT  *
FROM    results;
```

Its objective is to, starting from the bottom of a hierarchy, collect the anchor's parent (8a3d6714-27fa-4d1f-962f-9047d616ab42 in the above example; there is only one parent per row) all the way up to a point where there is a element without a parent. If successful, using my database, it should yield the following:

```
id                                       parent_id
------------------------------------     ------------------------------------
8a3d6714-27fa-4d1f-962f-9047d616ab42     babc74e8-1b6f-49e8-a1e3-a176fce2975d
babc74e8-1b6f-49e8-a1e3-a176fce2975d     3f83c9a2-bf43-46d8-bf87-070f5b55ae5a
3f83c9a2-bf43-46d8-bf87-070f5b55ae5a     69c074c6-a329-42c3-8e2e-5da9ab0ef81e
69c074c6-a329-42c3-8e2e-5da9ab0ef81e     bccab264-027c-4c4f-9ae8-3409efc6aeb3 
bccab264-027c-4c4f-9ae8-3409efc6aeb3     227db39a-2219-4abb-a2a7-3d28bf47ac01
227db39a-2219-4abb-a2a7-3d28bf47ac01
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Regards
Rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

```
QProjects results = new QProjects("results");
QProjects p = new QProjects("p");
QProjects t = new QProjects("t");
String id = "8a3d6714-27fa-4d1f-962f-9047d616ab42";


query.withRecursive(results, subQuery()
    .unionAll(
        subQuery().from(p).where(p.id.eq(id)).list(p.id, p.parentId),
        subQuery().from(t).innerJoin(results).on(results.parentId.eq(t.id)).list(t.id, t.parentId)))
    .from(results)
    .list(results.id, results.parentId);
```

Comment: Let me know whether it works coz I haven't tested it in real environment. Thanks...

Comment: I'm having difficulties integrating this into my environment. I had to define query: PostgresTemplates template = new PostgresTemplates();
Configuration config = new Configuration(template);JPASQLQuery query = new JPASQLQuery(em,config); I guess it is correct. I do not know where subQuery comes from; any thoughts?